# Having trouble declaring and calling a function including arrays and integers

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This is the part where I'm supposed to call the method "methodA":

```
for(GenNumber = 1; GenNumber < generations; GenNumber++) 
    {
        for(cellNumber = 0; cellNumber < totalCount; cellNumber++) 
        {
            row[cellNumber] = cells[cellNumber];
        }
        for(cellNumber = 1; cellNumber <= count; cellNumber++)
        {
            if(rule.equals(ruleA) == true) 
            {
                row[cellNumber] = methodA(cellNumber, row); //here I try to call it
            }
```

And this is method "methodA":

```
    public static boolean methodA(int cellNumber, int row) {
    int state = 0;
    if(row[cellNumber-1] == true)
    {
        state++;
    }
    if(row[cellNumber+1] == true)
    {
        state++;
    }
    if(row[cellNumber] == true && state != 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(row[cellNumber] == false && state != 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting 10 errors saying "array required, but int found". I'm obviously doing something wrong and I don't even know what. Mind you that I am very new to programming so don't be too harsh please. :)

Comment: row is of type int and not an array ... change your function parameter to  public static boolean methodA(int cellNumber, int[] row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

row is of type int and not an array ... change your function parameter to take in an array of int ...

```
public static boolean methodA(int cellNumber, int[] row)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I did that and now I'm getting another error saying: "incompatible types: boolean[] cannot be converted to int[]. What should I do?

Comment: What is the type of row ? is it boolean [] row ? then change the parameter to public static boolean methodA(int cellNumber, boolean[] row)

Comment: Ah thanks a lot bro! That finally got my code working!

Answer (score 0):

Your `methodA` prototype says that it takes two int parameters, but you are calling it with an int and an `int[]` (ie an array of ints) in the following line:

```
row[cellNumber] = methodA(cellNumber, row);
```

Either change your function call or its prototype then.

Answer (score 0):

Change declaration of methodA in foloving way

```
public static boolean methodA(int cellNumber, int[] row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Change the code as below

```
for(GenNumber = 1; GenNumber < generations; GenNumber++) 
    {
        for(cellNumber = 0; cellNumber < totalCount; cellNumber++) 
        {
            row[cellNumber] = cells[cellNumber];
        }
        for(cellNumber = 1; cellNumber <= count; cellNumber++)
        {
            if(rule.equals(ruleA) == true) 
            {
                row[cellNumber] = methodA(cellNumber, row); //here I try to call it
            }
```

And this is method "methodA":

```
public static boolean methodA(int cellNumber, int[] row) {
int state = 0;
if(row[cellNumber-1] == true)
{
    state++;
}
if(row[cellNumber+1] == true)
{
    state++;
}
if(row[cellNumber] == true && state != 1)
{
    return false;
}
else if(row[cellNumber] == false && state != 0)
{
    return true;
}
```

}

You need change the method signature for the method "methodA"

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. I did that and now I'm getting another error saying: "incompatible types: boolean[] cannot be converted to int[]. What should I do?

Comment: methodA(int cellNumber, int[] row) Change to  methodA(int cellNumber, boolean[] row)